# How do I right align div elements?

Tags: css, html

The body of my html document consists of 3 elements, a button, a form, and a canvas. I want the button and the form to be right aligned and the canvas to stay left aligned. The problem is when I try to align the first two elements, they no longer follow each other and instead are next to each other horizontally?, heres the code I have so far, I want the form to follow directly after the button on the right with no space in between.

```css
#cTask {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#button {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

#addEventForm {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid #003B62;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-color: #B5CFE0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="timeline.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="000" TEXT="FFFFFF">
  <div id="button">
    <button onclick="showForm()" type="button" id="cTask">
        Create Task
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="addEventForm">
    <form>
      <p><label>Customer name: <input></label></p>
      <p><label>Telephone: <input type=tel></label></p>
      <p><label>E-mail address: <input type=email></label></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myBoard" width="600" height="600" style="background:lightgray;">
      <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 577, accepted):

You can make a div that contains both the form & the button, then make the div float to the right by setting `float: right;`.

Comment: Never thought I'd be using float. I tried `margin-left: auto;` but that didn't work which surprised me because the element I'm trying to align to the right is relative.

Comment: @DFSFOT The opposite happened to me. Expected float:right to work but margin-left: auto did the trick, thanks.

Comment: This didn't have an effect in my case, the `style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: 0;" ` did though (credits to @pstanton).

Comment: what does "float: right" equals to?

Comment: @AndreasL. 's solution worked like charm

Answer (score 859):

Floats are okay, but problematic with IE 6 & 7.

I'd prefer using the following on the inner div:

```css
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: 0;
```

See [the IE Double Margin Bug](https://cssdeck.com/blog/double-margin-float-bug/) for clarification on why.

Comment: perfect solution! better than float because it preserves height

Comment: Shouldn't use px in 0 values.

Comment: @ShellNinja why? i know `0` is valid, however so is 0px... argue your point so we learn something.

Comment: Leaving out the unit allows the browser to skip certain calculations on render this improving performance. If it's zero why waste the resources computing the layout based on a unit? Zero is zero regardless of unit... One would think this logic would be built into browsers by now. [link](http://twoopz.tumblr.com/post/7021586127/css3-improve-performance-with-best-practices)

Comment: can't disagree but i doubt it impacts performance much. edit.

Comment: I can't get this to work, the div still aligns left. Could you provide a fiddle or some (more) lines of html/css?

Comment: Make sure your element has `display: block;`

Comment: Didn't work for me in IE 8 with `display: block` or `display: inline-block` on a div within a table cell - which I know isn't exactly the OP's question, but is what I believe would be a more common scenario...  Had to use `float: right`, and not liking the thought of non-backward-compatibility, unless this way (using margins on the div) just doesn't work in IE 8? Unless I just leave the margin adjustment code in the CSS for earlier IE versions, I guess.

Comment: Didn't work with an anchor I wanted to right align (on latest Firefox). Even tried adding "display: block" - see https://jsfiddle.net/birbilis/fg0mvb35/ - using float: right worked fine

Comment: Working examples: https://codepen.io/zurfyx/pen/NyKWjm https://codepen.io/zurfyx/pen/KQPKqP

Comment: This requires the inner element to be a block and to have a fixed width.

Comment: Can alternatively use ```margin: 0 0 0 auto;``` if you'd like to put all your margin styles in one line. Using ```0``` or ```0px``` are both considered fine, the main thing is to be consistent in your project and stick to one of them.

Comment: great solution! but i disagree: floats are not ok. in many situations they will mess with text layout, even with horrid clearfixes in place.

Comment: on chrome 96 `display: block` worked for me, but `display: inline-block` didn't work for me

Comment: Just use `margin:0 auto;` It's much better.

Answer (score 427):

Old answers.  An update: use flexbox, pretty much works in all browsers now.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <div>I'm on the right</div>
</div>
```

And you can get even fancier, simply:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

And fancier:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
   <div>Left</div>
   <div>Middle</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but when screen gets small instead of stacking they just get really narrow

Comment: You need to add a media query to change flex-direction from row to column at the breaking point you define.  You will likely want to change or remove your justify-content in this example otherwise things will stretch up and down instead of left and right.

Comment: Works for me, but I also added (in the first example) a float: right, so the paragraph on the right does not mess the lines in the left.

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 60):

You can use `flexbox` with `flex-grow` to push the last element to the right.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1;">Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I personally feel this is the correct answer for 2020 :P

Answer (score 41):

*Note that while this answer is not wrong, it is very outdated methodology written in 2015*

---

Other answers for this question are not so good since `float:right` can go outside of a parent div (overflow: hidden for parent sometimes might help) and `margin-left: auto, margin-right: 0` for me didn't work in complex nested divs (I didn't investigate why).

I've figured out that for certain elements `text-align: right` works, assuming this works when the element and parent are both `inline` or `inline-block`.

Note: the `text-align` CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. `text-align` does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

An example:

```
<div style="display: block; width: 80%; min-width: 400px; background-color: #caa;">
    <div style="display: block; width: 100%">
        I'm parent
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 100%">
        Caption for parent
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/6k4bmwLv/).

Comment: This worked for me for aligning 3 images to the right with <br /> tags in between them.

Comment: To be clear: this doesn't right-align the div itself. Each of the two child divs "parent/caption" occupy the full width of the screen, as you can see by setting their background-color. What you've done is align the text within them.

Answer (score 31):

If you have multiple divs that you want aligned side by side at the right end of the parent div, set `text-align: right;` on the parent div.

Answer (score 23):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6PyrK/1

You can add the attributes of `float:right` and `clear:both;` to the form and button

Answer (score 15):

Maybe just:

```
  margin: auto 0 auto auto;
```

Comment: @SoniSol Which link?

Answer (score 12):

Simple answer is here:

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    anything:
    <select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality" class="cls" style="width: 200px; height: 28px; overflow:auto;">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes float: left leads to design problems, for that cases you can use display flex like this:

```css
.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

One way could be setting a **parent div** for those elements that need to be pulled right (float: **right**;) and do the rest like the way shown in the the example below to have them right-aligned:

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*Below: child-div styling is not needed for this purpose! this is just for demonstration:*/

.child-div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: powderblue;
  margin: auto 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="">CANVAS div </div>
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">child 1</div>
  <div class="child-div">child 2</div>
  <div class="child-div">...</div>
  <div class="child-div">child n</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you are using bootstrap, then:**

```
<div class="pull-right"></div>
```

Comment: I think you meant `<div class="text-right"></div>`.

Comment: anil isn't wrong, class "pull-right" results in "float: right;" (tested with Bootstrap 3.4.1)

Answer (score 3):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

hasnt been mentioned. if there are 2 elements (even if one is an empty div) it will place one on the left and one on the right.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div id="emptyDiv"></div>
  <div>I'm on the right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I am correct. You can also change to justify-content: end; so you won't need the emptyDiv element.

Comment: yes flex end has been stated in another answer, however no answer has mentioned this method. the advantage of this method is that if you want to add any more elements it wont effect the position of the "im on the right" div as long as it is the final child of its parent and also provided there is enough space in the row.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to support IE9 and below you can use flexbox to solve this: [codepen](http://codepen.io/Bates550/pen/VmeOBP)

There's also a few bugs with IE10 and 11 ([flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), but they are not present in this example

You can vertically align the `<button>` and the `<form>` by wrapping them in a container with `flex-direction: column`. The source order of the elements will be the order in which they're displayed from top to bottom so I reordered them.

You can then horizontally align the form & button container with the canvas by wrapping them in a container with `flex-direction: row`. Again the source order of the elements will be the order in which they're displayed from left to right so I reordered them.

Also, this would require that you remove all `position` and `float` style rules from the code linked in the question.

Here's a trimmed down version of the HTML in the codepen linked above.

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="formContainer">
    <div id="addEventForm"> 
      <form></form>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
      <button></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS

```
#mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
} 

#formContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use padding-left:60% (for ex) to align your content to right and simultaneously wrap the content in responsive container (I required navbar in my case)
to ensure it works in all examples.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it easy by just add this css:
(Works in IE11)

```html
<div>
<!-- Subtract with the amount of your element width -->
<span style="margin-left: calc(100vw - 50px)">Right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless you know the exact width of each element you are right-aligning. *Extremely* fragile solution to the point of impracticality.

Answer (score -15):

I know this is an old post but couldn't you just use `<div id=xyz align="right">` for right.

You can just replace right with left, center and justify.

Worked on my site:)

Comment: Please don't use HTML attributes to format your page. That's what CSS was made for. In fact, the `align` attribute is [now deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features).

Comment: ...and hence the reason for a question like this and the need for it to be answered, since old methods no longer work.

Comment: ohohoh, so much negative))

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was wondering why `align="right"` was wrong, and lo and behold, you mentioned it and someone provided a solid counter-answer in the form of a comment :)