# Right align element in div class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 2 with Bootstrap 4 and [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/component/card). However, I am having trouble right align the elements inside my container div. I want both my button and text to be aligned to the right hand side

Here is what the code that I have tried to produce the result as shown in the photo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <p class="d-inline pull-right">Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Right align failed]

I have also tried this solution from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693224/how-do-i-right-align-div-elements)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="asdf">
    <p class="d-inline pull-right">Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">+</button>
  </div>
</div>

.asdf {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Both of these solutions does not move the elements to the right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've removed the class `pull-right` class from both the `button` and the `p` tag and added `text-right` class to the `div.container`.

*I think this is what you need.*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container text-right">
    <p class="d-inline">Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-inline">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Sumesh. Works like a charm. This has been bother me for so long. What do you recommend to get this right? How did you find out what was the problem since Harekrishna mentioned the previous code works in the online editor but not my program (And I have confirmed that is indeed the case)

Comment: Actually i don't know why your code didn't work. But the items with display:inline-block property is following the text-align of the parent element and can be aligned with respect to the parent element text-align property.

Comment: class="d-inline" worked for me
thanks Sumesh

Answer (score 24):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Because of new RTL support, `*-left` and `*-right` classes have changed to `*-start` and `*-end`. Here are the Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 conversions:

- `float-left` => `float-start`
- `float-right` => `float-end`
- `ml-auto` => `ms-auto`
- `mr-auto` => `me-auto`

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

In Bootstrap 4, `pull-right` has been replaced with `float-right`.

**If `float-right` is not working,** remember that **Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox**, and many elements are `display:flex` which can prevent `float-right` from working. In some cases, the utility classes like `align-self-end` or `ml-auto` work to right align elements that are inside a flexbox container like a Bootstrap 4 .row, Card or Nav. The `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) is used in a flexbox element to push elements to the right.

Also, remember that `text-right` still works on inline elements.

[Bootstrap 4 align right examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/nTobetXAwb)

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to handle to use the align option

```
<div class="col-sm-12" align="right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Approve</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. Just copy and paste your code in any online bootstrap editor, you will get the right result. But you can write it in a more structured way

HTML code:

```
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 .asdf">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">+</button>
              <p class="pull-right">Some text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS code

```
.asdf {
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of bootstrap is to avoid comment CSS like this. I suggest referring to their documentation for more inept usage of their tools.