# How to align right a series of images in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have a group of images and I want to put them on the right in a block. It's what I tried:

```
   <div class="row" >
        <div class="float-right">
            <img src="1.png"/>
            <img src="2.jpg"/>
            <img src="3.jpg"/>
            <img src="4.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the images are still all on the left. If I remove "row" or replace it with something like `d-block` they go to the right, however the division overlaps existing ones!!

Comment: What do you mean "the division overlaps existing ones" ? The Bootstrap `row` is *only* meant to contain columns (`col-*`), and since it's flexbox, float won't work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146263/bootstrap-4-align-elements-right-inside-a-col-div/43146307#43146307

Comment: @zim thanks, that's my answer! anyway, what else should use to have the row functionality wihout having col-*?

Comment: You can just use `d-flex`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">...</div>
```

The `d-flex` class makes your wrapping div a flexbox layout, the images should be direct children of this div. The `justify-content-end` class makes all the images align to the right side of the row.

Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content