# align element in footer to right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have footer,where i have copyright mark with name and also instagram link, which i want align to the right. Nothing work, can you help me please? Im using bootstrap.

```
<footer class="text-center bg-dark py-3" style="color: white;">
  <span>name &nbsp</span><span style="color:#d64161">©2021 &nbsp</span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/dtd_quiz/" target="_blank"><i style="color: white;" class="fab fa-instagram"> instagram</i></a>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: remove `text-center` class from footer and add `text-right`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 align elements right inside a col div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146263/bootstrap-4-align-elements-right-inside-a-col-div)

Answer (score 2):

change `text-center` to `text-right`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-P5MgMn1jBN01asBgU0z60Qk4QxiXo86+wlFahKrsQf37c9cro517WzVSPPV1tDKzhku2iJ2FVgL67wG03SGnNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<footer class="text-right bg-dark py-3" style="color: white;">
   <span>name &nbsp</span><span style="color:#d64161">©2021 &nbsp</span>
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dtd_quiz/" target="_blank">
      <i style="color: white;" class="fab fa-instagram"> instagram</i>
   </a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1. Use text-right class on `footer` element,
2. on the first `span` give these 2 classes: `d-inline-block` and `ml-auto` and `d-flex` to `footer`;

I would suggest the first one.

please let me know if this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
footer.text-center.bg-dark.py-3 {
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

Comment: its not advisable, if you already have a class in bootstrap to do your things, why to write custom css?

Comment: Yes but if he doesn't know about that. I also know that there is a class. he also has that option so it is up to him. I gave him one solution.