# Move the widget to the right side of the web page using bootstrap 4

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4

I want the information tag to be at the right side of the web page. Rest of the things are in the middle of the page. While I am not able to move the information to the right side. Also, because of it the footer disappeared. While I remove the information code, the footer works. Please help me right-align the information widget and also have the footer too.

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="card border-light mb-3 text-center">
            <p class="card-header">Videos</p>
        </div>
         <div id="userSuccess" class="hide" role="alert">
            <div id="successUserContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="userVid"> 
            <?php
            $allVid = Schema::getAll();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($allVid); $i++) {
                echo <<<HTML
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card h-100">  
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="vid.php"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
                            <h4 class="card-title">{$allVid[$i]->getTitle()} </h4>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
    HTML;
            }
            ?>   
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
        <div class="card my-4">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Information</h5> 
                    <div class="card-body">  
                        <div class="row">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">  
                                    <li>
                                        ...  
                                    </li>
                                </ul>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
<?php
require_once './page/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Did you see the duplicate questions?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050553/right-align-element-in-div-class-with-bootstrap-4/48997651 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146263/bootstrap-4-align-elements-right-inside-a-col-div or

Answer (score 0):

For right align, you'll want to add the class of "justify-content-end" after your "row" class.

```
<div class="row justify-content-end"><!-- ADDED HERE-->
  <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
    <div class="card my-4">
      <h5 class="card-header">Information</h5>
        <!-- REST OF YOUR CODE-->
```

For your footer, you'll need to wrap your URL in parenthesis.

```
<?php require_once('/yourdirectory/yourfooter.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Hey with this code the widget is on the right side now but I want it to be nex to the video card-header. While it is under the cards but to the right. Also the footer is still hidden.