# how to push the whole table object to the right?

Tags: html, css

This was asked probably many times, but I tried a lots and still couldn't figure it out. Here is [the site](http://alumnigolf2018.com/) I am working on, regardless what's the platform (wordpress in this case), it really is a question about how to write css.

On the right top there is a event table, above the event table is a contact section with email/phone.

What I need is simple: to push the table to the right side and align with the contact section.

At this moment what I tried is from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693224/how-do-i-right-align-div-elements) and it is not working.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me sort it out. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `float: right;` is the most basic choice. There are other, more complicated ones.

Comment: don't know why it is not working in my case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you write below code

```
.css-events-list{width: 100%;}
.events-table{float:right;}
```

please check the screenshot how it will be look like after added those `css` 
[click here](https://prnt.sc/gix6c0)

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe it was working already but showed not working due to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
.css-events-list{
   text-align: center;
}
.css-events-list > table{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**OR**

```
.css-events-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't see there is a .css-events-list in the initial style.css, I added it in the style.css, but no, it is not working, maybe can you tell me where is the original .css-events-list from?

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourobject {
  float: right;
}
```

You might want to make some adjustments to for the media device automatically.