# how to make two elements align right

Tags: html, css

I have a button and a textarea:

[image]

```css
.text2
{
    font-size:15px;
    resize:none;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#btn1
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input1"   class="text2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your writing..." onpropertychange="cop()" oninput="cop()"></textarea>
<button onclick="saveText()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> save as</button>
```

Now I want to make them align right or left just like this:

[image]

How can the run code snippet button and the textarea be aligned left?

Comment: Your button and your `<textarea>` *already* occupy the same line. Did you want the button *below* the `<textarea>`?

Comment: yeah...I want to put <textarea> in the first row and <button> in the second row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I right align div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693224/how-do-i-right-align-div-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way to do that. The basic idea is to make your text area DOM occupy the entire row. Depends on your need, you can either mark text area as `display: block`, or using `flex-column`.

## Using display: block

```css
.text2
{
    font-size:15px;
    resize:none;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;

    /* add this line to make this element occupy the entire line */
    display: block;
}

#btn1
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input1"   class="text2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your writing..." onpropertychange="cop()" oninput="cop()"></textarea>
<button onclick="saveText()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> save as</button>
```

## Using flex

```css
/* wrap child element in flex with column direction works too */
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.text2
{
    font-size:15px;
    resize:none;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#btn1
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea id="input1"   class="text2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your writing..." onpropertychange="cop()" oninput="cop()"></textarea>
    <button onclick="saveText()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> save as</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! You help me a lot!

Comment: No problem. I found I forget `display: block` in flex example. We don't need that when using flex.. The example code now updated.

Answer (score 0):

To move your button below your **[`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)**, you have a number of options.

You could make the `<textarea>` take up a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** of `100%`, so that the button wouldn't have space to occupy, thus forcing it to the next row:

```css
.text2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#btn1 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input1" class="text2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your writing..." onpropertychange="cop()" oninput="cop()"></textarea>
<button onclick="saveText()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> save as</button>
```

Or you could keep `80%` `width` and set the button as a **[block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** with **[`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**:

```css
.text2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

#btn1 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input1" class="text2" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your writing..." onpropertychange="cop()" oninput="cop()"></textarea>
<button onclick="saveText()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> save as</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It does help me!