# Right Align Div CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to right align a div on my navigation bar for my website. The goal is to align the div so it's always aligned in the same place towards the right of the webpage. I've tried margins, CSS positioning, and changing the div to `display: inline-block;`

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.nav-bar {
  z-index: 98;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-img {
  height: 100px;
}

.nav-options {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-option {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.1);
  color: white;
}

p,
ul,
ol,
li,
select {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.line {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 0.5px;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-menu {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 98;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: -6%;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mobile-options {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 110%;
}

.mobile-option {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: large;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.8);
  border: none;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.exit-btn {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 75%;
  left: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="desktop-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="nav-option">About Us</button>
      <button class="nav-option">Classes</button>
      <button class="nav-option">Contact Us</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
                    <div class="line"></div><br>
                    <div class="line"></div><br>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are many ways to right-align something.

Comment: @mpen Ok, I added the code above

Comment: Great start. Now to which div are you referring? The mobile version or desktop version?

Comment: @mpen The contents of the mobile ```<nav>``` tag.   ```<nav class="mobile-nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="nav-img"></a>
    <div class="nav-options">
      <button class="hamburger-menu" id="mobile-menu-enter">
                    <div class="line"></div><br>
                    <div class="line"></div><br>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </button>
    </div>
  </nav>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the `position` to `absolute` and using `vw` as the property for the `left` attribute.

```
.hamburger-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: right;`.

You can also find other solutions here [How do I right align div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693224/how-do-i-right-align-div-elements)

Comment: I've already tried float. I added my code above so you can better understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **position** ***absolute*** to remove the element from the DOM and move your element anywhere ***relative*** to the first containing parent element up the DOM tree that has a position set. Then use positioning props like `top`, `right`, `bottom` and/or `left` to move the element on the page.

See MDN on [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more info

```css
  :root {
  --padding: .5em;
}

/* This is the parent element, set its position to relative
so the right-div will be positioneed relative to it */
#parent {
  background: red;
  padding: .5em;
  position: relative;
}

#first-div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: var(--padding);
}

p {
  padding: var(--padding);
  background: white;
}

/* set this divs position to absolute so its top, left, bottom, right 
positioning props will be relative to its closest parent set to relative */
#right-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(var(--padding) + 0px);
  top: calc(var(--padding) + 0px);
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: var(--padding);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first-div">This is the first div</div>
  <p>This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a
    paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph</p>
  <div id="right-div">This is the right div</div>
</div>
```